# Как называются __DATE__ и прочие подобные вещи

Tags: php

Я не знаю как искать такие вещи с двумя нижними подчёркиваниями.

```
__DATE__
__TIME__
```

Comment: Волшебные _(или "магические")_ константы: [Волшебные константы](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое!

Answer (score 2):

Есть на данный момент 9 особых констант с отличающимся поведением, называемые [магическими константами](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). 8 из них записываются схожим видом `__слово__`. Но это написание не зарезервировано языком, вы можете объявлять свои константы.

`__DATE__` и `__TIME__` в число магических констант не входят и в самом PHP не определены. Это просто константы, которые у вас объявлены где-то в коде через функцию [`define`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) либо синтаксис [`const`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php)